# Docker - Windows contaier exits after script

Tags: docker, containers, windows-container

I have made a few containers (which run in the Unix environment where the entrypoint is a script file. These script files usually manage some configuration and then carries on executing the CMD by using the exec "$@". While creating/testing such an image I usually return to the command prompt so I manually can assert the configurations. This works fine.
However, today I was making a similar image but based on the windows container (microsoft/nanoserver) and here I ran into a few problems.

1) I made a powershell script to do the configuration but in powershell I can't use the exec "$@" to relay the execution to the CMD. What is the equivalent in a windows container?

2) If I create an image based on microsoft/nanoserver and just copy in some files you will stay in interactive mode (if you run the container with -it params of course). But as soon as I point the ENTRYPOINT to a powershell script, the container will terminate immediately after running the script, even though I append a cmd to the run command.

So basically my question is: How do I get it to enter the command prompt after executing a script? (with windows container).

Comment: Below works fine for me. Running a script and returning prompt # escape=`
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]
entrypoint powershell.exe {Write-output "hello"}; powershell.exe

Comment: Thanks Gregory, I got it working as i wanted.
However I have no idead of what 
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]
does.
Also its a little strange that we need to have two powershell.exe statements in the ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: @Galtrold You don't. With `SHELL ["powershell"]`, your `ENTRYPOINT` is run by powershell.exe, so it can be any valid Powershell expression. You can run the script file directly or `Invoke-Expression` it.

Comment: Consider this docker container that uses a script as an entrypoint https://github.com/PhilippHeuer/docker-gitlab-powershell

Answer (score -1):

this question is similar to
[How to keep WIndows Container running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309188/how-to-keep-windows-container-running)

if you add at the end of your dockerfile

```
ping -t localhost
```

it should leave it running (...unless there is some other errors in the file, of course)