# How to keep WIndows Container running?

Tags: docker-for-windows, windows-container

I need to keep my Windows Container up so I can run further commands on it using `docker exec`.

On Linux, I'd start it to run either `sleep infinity`, or `tail -f /dev/null`. Alternatively, I could [borrow `pause.c` from Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/16d33c49858579fbe13df52c065dbea6627e9aef/build/pause/pause.c).

What does this look like on Windows?

Comment: `powershell start-sleep 200000`. Why would you want to have this instead of using your executable as entrypoint

Comment: To test my app. I am using the Docker SDK for Python to manipulate the container interactively as if it was a virtual machine. In a pytest test, first I start it, then copy my app on it, run `container.exec_run("some command")` few times, assert that everything went well, then destroy the container.

Comment: Well stuff above or just `ping -t 127.0.0.1` will do it

Comment: K8s apparently uses ping. If you'd post it as answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ping -t localhost` will do it

Comment: Isn't there something less weird? This pollutes the log.

Comment: Try `cmd /c ping -t localhost > NUL`, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81298.

Answer (score 4):

[Kubernetes on Windows used to use ping](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/000d1febb8129cbab02666d4095a66130a8febbb/parts/k8s/windowskubeletfunc.ps1#L155)

```
cmd /c ping -t localhost
```

This would [print lots of unnecessary output](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/81298), so a good improvement should be

```
cmd /c ping -t localhost > NUL
```

What Kubernetes does now is to [run a custom pauseloop.exe binary](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-windows-tools/tree/1113abc0c516311f3bb650f9907f4a71f9f08141/cmd/wincat).

In late 2022, the current home for wincat/pauseloop is https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/build%2Fpause%2Fwindows%2Fwincat. The move was implemented in https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-windows-tools/pull/270.

Answer (score 4):

A full run command would be:

```bsh
docker run -d --name YourContainer mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 ping -t localhost
```

**Note:** Make sure 1809 is equal with your own windows version from `[WIN]`+`[R]` -> `winver`.

You should then be able to step into the running container instance with the name `YourContainer`:

```bsh
docker exec -it YourContainer cmd
```